# Join function and dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the below code

```
>>> ",".join({"x": 1, "y": 2})
 'y,x'

>>> list({"x": 1, "y": 2})
 ['y', 'x']
```

On what logic is the key printed in the order "y,x" and not "x,y". I tried with multiple values in the dictionary but unable to conclude a logic.

Comment: it is because dictionary does not have any order

Comment: What is your question?